# How to prove or disprove this statement about convergent sub-sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove through a proof or disprove through a counter example that if $a_n$ is a sequence which has three sub-limits ( $a_n$ has three sub-sequences that each one of them have different limit)and $b_n$ is another sequence that has  two sub-limits( $b_n$ has two sub-sequences that each one of them have different limit) then could it be that there is a sequence $c_n$ that happens to be
 $c_n$=$a_n$+$b_n$ and is convergent ? (convergent here means that $c_n$ has only one limit!!) any piece of advice is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

No (assuming that "has two sub-limits" is understood as "has *exactly* two sub-limits).

Let the three sub-limits of $a_n$ be $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ and assume $c_n=a_n+b_n\to \gamma$.
For a subsequence $n_k$ such that $a_{n_k}\to \alpha_i$, we still have $c_{n_k}\to c$, hence $b_{n_k}=c_{n_k}-a_{n_k}\to\gamma-\alpha_i$, i.e., $b_n$ has (at least) the three disticnt sub-limits $c-\alpha_1$, $c-\alpha_2$, $c-\alpha_3$.

Comment: Yes, the question is critically ambiguous about whether there are precisely two sublimits.

Comment: @Frank: Not really. If I tell you I have two brothers, you would be surprised to learn that in fact I had three.

Comment: @TonyK A fairly absurd analogy in a mathematical context. Saying an object $X$ has $n$ $Y$'s just about always means 'at least $n$'.

Comment: @Frank: That is nonsense.

Comment: @TonyK So according to you, the natural interpretation of the statement: $(c_n)$ has a convergent subsequence is: $(c_n)$ has precisely one convergent subsequence? Quick, rewrite all the analysis textbooks.

Comment: @Frank: No, that would be the natural interpretation of the statement "$(c_n)$ has one convergent subsequence". For instance: "If a sequence has one convergent subsequence, prove that the sequence is either convergent or unbounded."

Comment: @TonyK OK thanks I understand now. I would always still expect to see the word 'exactly' appearing...

Comment: @TonyK The case of a sequence haveing *exactly* one convergent subsequence does not occur. Any subsequence of a convergent subsequence, as well as any subsequence differing only in finitely many terms from it is also convergent.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: You are absolutely right. I should have said "If a sequence has one limit point, prove that the sequence is either convergent or unbounded."